How to find identical files in a directory tree
I would like to identify the identical files in a directory tree of a Synology NAS.
Is there a way to do it robustly and efficiently?
Here's what I tried:
basedir=/volume1/bordel

find "$basedir" -type f -exec md5sum {} + |
sort -k1,1 |
uniq -d

But I get no output, which is impossible

Two identical files will still have a different path, so uniq won't see them as repeated.

Indeed, I realized it just now

you might find fdupes usefule

@Rorschach fdupes seems promising, but compiling it in the NAS might prove difficult

use … | uniq -dw 32 to only check the first 32 characters.

@pmf that would take care of the job. Now I'm trying to understand why some entries can start with \, for eg. \d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ta\nta

so why not use a program for that, like fdupes? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277697/whats-the-quickest-way-to-find-duplicated-files https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71176/find-duplicate-files https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570305/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-duplicate-files https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678461/finding-duplicate-files-with-same-filename-and-exact-same-size https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705733/find-duplicate-files-but-specify-a-directory-to-keep did you try researching?

@pmf it seems that the leading backslash means that the filename is escaped.

@KamilCuk Sorry, I didn't research it outside of SO. The method in your first link is the same as what I came up here, but there's that backslash that appears at the start of the md5 of some files; I need to handle it somehow. BTW, external utilities are a no-go as I won't be cross-compiling them for the NAS.

There a backslash at the start of md5? How is that possible? I suspect your file names or input have dos line endings. Check them with hexdump or cat -v.

@KamilCuk @Fravadona In some versions of md5sum, the line starts with a backslash if the filename contains a backslash or newline character.

If your filenames are with newlines and slashes and odd, use zero streams  find -print0 md5sum -z sort -z uniq -z . man md5sum says that filename escaping is disabled with zero stream.s

Using GNU versions of tools; find . -type f -exec md5sum -z {} + | sort -z -k1,1 | uniq -z -w32 -D | tr '\0' '\n' would work.

Thanks @M.NejatAydin; that would be a great answer but the md5sum of the NAS doesn't support the -z option (md5sum (GNU coreutils) 8.24)

@Fravadona Then, perhaps, find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sed 's/^\\//' | sort -k1,1 | uniq -w32 -D

@M.NejatAydin yes, I was thinking of moving the backslash to the end of the md5 hash,

@Fravadona In that case, this should work, if your uniq supports -D and -w options: find . -type f -exec md5sum  {} + | sed 's/^\\\(.*\)/\1\\/' | sort -k1,1 | uniq -w32 -D | sed 's/\(.*\)\\$/\\\1/'

@M.NejatAydin Yes, uniq -Dw32 works on the NAS, but here you're moving the backslash at the end of the line, I can't agree with it as it might conflict with the end of the filename

@Fravadona The last sed command will place the backslash at the beginning of the line again. This won't conflict with anything, because, if the filename contains a backslash then the md5sum line always starts with a backslash.

@M.NejatAydin Ah, you're right. Can you post it as an answer?

If your uniq supports -D and -w options:
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + |
sed 's/^\\\(.*\)/\1\\/'          |
sort -k1,1                       |
uniq -w32 -D                     |
sed 's/\(.*\)\\$/\\\1/'

The sed commands are to rectify the md5sum lines that begin with a backslash character. In some versions of md5sum, lines begin with a backslash if the filename contains a newline or backslash character (and those characters are escaped with backslashes in the filenames; \n and \\).
The -w 32 option of uniq is to compare only 32 characters at the beginning of the lines, and the -D option prints all duplicated lines (in the first 32 characters). These options are GNU extensions.

I don't see the use of that +-sign at the end of your find. I tried this on my computer and it worked:
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort -k1,1 | uniq -d

Good luck

The + argument to -exec is nonstandard but widely supported. It is more efficient than \; which creates a new process for each file. With + you get as many files as possible passed to the command, like xargs does too.

@triplee the + is standard https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html

I hope that's not the reason for your downvote: I tried the command from the author and it failed because of that +-sign, so I replaced it by the \; causing it to work. I admit that I'm working on a WSL, which might be different than the system of the question author. Nevertheless it is a situation which works while the system does not seem to work on the author's system.
